# CMS that creates separate discussion page for each article

Tags: linux, open-source, cms

I’m looking for a CMS (it can also be a specialized CMS, e.g., a blog or a wiki) that should come* with the following functionality.

(* I know that this can be done with most CMS, but I’m especially looking for a solution that ships with this functionality, which means that it must either be activated by default or it must be possible to enable it in the options/configuation/GUI. So it should especially not require editing any files or creating/installing a module.)

For each page/article that gets published, a separate discussion page should be created automatically.

#### Article page

The link to the discussion page needs to be added automatically.

Bonus points if the article author can choose to disable the creation of a discussion page.

#### Discussion page

It must contain:

- comment form (*)
- list of all published comments (no pagination!)
- link back to the article (not its fulltext nor a snippet)

(* Note that this should be a regular comment form, so not wiki-style editing of the whole page, like it’s the case with [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki).)

Bonus points if this page also lists [linkbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkback) for the article.

#### URLs

The URL for the article should be chosen by the author. The URL for the discussion page should be created automatically.

When the article has the URL `/article/foobar`, the discussion page should either be at `/discussion/foobar` or `/article/foobar/discussion` (or something similar).

---

- MUST be **FLOSS** (Free/Libre Open Source Software).
- MUST run natively on a **GNU/Linux** server. Please no Java.

Comment: So, basically you are asking for something like *[Wordpress with separate comments pages](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/separate-comments-from-specified-posts?replies=11)*? ;) I won't be writing up an answer because [it's known – at least – since 2008 that Wordpress can do that](http://www.scriptygoddess.com/archives/2008/11/08/put-comments-on-a-separate-page-in-wordpress/). In fact, I bet most well-vetted CMSs will have alike functionality that simply takes a bit of editing to make it work (and look) the way you prefer.

Comment: @e-sushi: As I explained in my first paragraph, I know that most CMS would allow to do this somehow. But I’m especially looking for a CMS that ships with this feature.

Comment: I did read your first paragraph. Please note that the Wordpress solution *“ships with the CMS”*. No 3rd-party plugins, modules, or anything alike involved. **It's all in the WP core.** Simply create the according theme files and adapt the .htaccess and you're done. Looking at your text again, my recommendation-comment fulfils all the requirements you've listed. If you are looking something else (or a more specific functionality), you should probably edit your question accordingly to enable people to post more helpful comments and answers.

Comment: @e-sushi: I don’t know WordPress’ architecture, but manually editing PHP (or any files at all, for that matter) is not my definition of "ships with" (the WP solution would be similar to creating a plugin yourself, it just happens to be done in theme files) -- otherwise any CMS that allows editing core files or adding custom functions etc. would be a valid answer. -- I thought my question was clear in that regard ("come with the following functionality"; "ships with this functionality"). Do you think I should add "must be enabled by default, or it must be possible to enable it in the options"?

Comment: Now I'm finally starting to understand what you're looking for. Hmmm, my humble opinion would be that it might indeed make sense to explicitly mention something along the lines you're suggesting as it might prevent people like me from thinking into the wrong direction – because sometimes, some of us forget that not everyone is willing or able to edit a PHP-based “theme file”… ;)

Comment: @e-sushi: Aye, I edited it. Thanks for your feedback :)

Answer (score 1):

MediaWiki offers a "regular comment form" too, just install the appropriate extension.

- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:DiscussionThreading (lightweight)
- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:LiquidThreads
- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Flow (requires node.js service)
- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Comments (this is the most used one among the recent ones)
- More! https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Discussion_and_forum_extensions